# Activation of Office for MAC offline

Tags: mac, microsoft-office

I have a problem activating Office for Mac on an offline laptop.  When I use the installer for Office for MAC it asks  for a email address to activate Office but of course I don't have internet so I can't do that.  I do however have the activation code for Office so I'm wondering if it's possible to get an installer that doesn't need an email to activate?

Answer (score 0):

Ever since 2013 they require online accounts.

Comment: So it's impossible to activate office offline on a MAC?  What if we get a business support contract?

Comment: Here is something I found with a little Google. Try at your own risk!

https://shaadlife.com/activate-office-2019-on-mac/

https://gist.github.com/zthxxx/9ddc171d00df98cbf8b4b0d8469ce90a#file-microsoft_office_2019_vl_serializer-pkg